# exporting DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot certificate using iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: iphone, ipad, certificate, fiddler

I am trying to setup a proxy on my Ipad so that I can capture it's traffic using fiddler2 but for some reason it's not helping.

I am following this blog post,

http://blog.brianbeach.com/2013/01/using-fiddler-with-iphoneipad.html

Now when I try to create a profile in iPhone Configuration Utility and try to export certificate as shown in picture below, it asks me for password which I never setup neither know of.

[image]

when i open an app on my iPad which uses webservices, gives me this error,

> Can't Verify Server Identity
>
> myAPP Can't verify the identity of "me.myWebsite.com". would
>   you like to continue anyway ?

app works when i remove proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the Configuration Utility.

You should simply follow these steps: http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2012/12/21/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices

Comment: I instead copied certificate to my desktop and sent it to ipad through email and just installed it. Thanks